# Does $k$ rep $m$ divide $k$ rep $n$ iff $m$ divides $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $k$ and $m$ be positive integers. I define a binary operation $k$ rep $m$ as the number you get when writing $k$ $m$ times in base ten. For example, $1$ rep $5$ $=$ $11111$, $23$ rep $2$ $=$ $2323$, and for any positive integer $k$, $k$ rep $1$ $=$ $k$. I conjecture that, for any positive integers $k$, $m$, and $n$, $k$ rep $m$ divides $k$ rep $n$ iff $m$ divides $n$. Is this true, and if so, what is the proof? Of course, one can generalize the operation rep to bases other than ten, such as base two or base three or any other base, and then ask an analogous question. I would like it if the generalized question was answered as well.

Comment: Special case of the fact that $\,f_n  = (x^n-1)/(x-1)\,$ is a strong divisibility sequence so $\,f_k\mid f_n\iff k\mid n,\ $ e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7479/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7561/242) in the dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is your conjecture *evidently* always true in every base, the quotient has a simple form in the base used: if $k$ has $d$ digits the quotient is $0\dots01$ rep $n/m$ where there are $d-1$ zeros in the repeating unit (hence $d$ digits in all). For example, in any base with the digits used,
$$513513513513513513=000001000001000001×513513$$